# Compare values across multiple columns in a dataframe for each cp_id

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like below . The cp_id are duplicated and has different values in each columns. I need to compare first occurence of each value in every column and compare it with all other for same cp_id. The result should be an additional column telling where there is a mismtach.

[image: Input Data]

The resulting dataframe should look like below :

[image: Resulting df]

What is the most optimal way to acheive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is test if number of unique values per groups is not `1` by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) and because multiple columns should be wrong is used [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names for error column, joined values are by `,`:

```
m = df.groupby('cp_id').transform('nunique').ne(1)
df['Result'] = m.dot(m.columns + ' is not match,').str[:-1]
```

**Details**:

```
print (m)
    p_code  channel  subchannel
0     True    False       False
1     True    False       False
2     True    False       False
3     True    False       False
4     True    False       False
5     True    False       False
6     True    False       False
7     True    False       False
8     True    False       False
9     True    False       False
10    True    False       False
11    True    False       False
12    True    False       False
13    True    False       False
14   False    False        True
15   False    False        True
16    True    False       False
17    True    False       False
18    True    False       False
19    True    False       False
20    True    False       False
```

If need comapre first value per groups ouput is different:

```
m = df.groupby('cp_id').transform('first').ne(df.drop('cp_id', axis=1))
df['Result'] = m.dot(m.columns + ' is not match,').str[:-1]
```

**Details**:

```
print (m)
    p_code  channel  subchannel
0    False    False       False
1     True    False       False
2    False    False       False
3     True    False       False
4    False    False       False
5     True    False       False
6     True    False       False
7     True    False       False
8    False    False       False
9     True    False       False
10   False    False       False
11    True    False       False
12   False    False       False
13    True    False       False
14   False    False       False
15   False    False        True
16   False    False       False
17    True    False       False
18   False    False       False
19   False    False       False
20    True    False       False
```